# Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseRecyclerOptions' but already tried implementations

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Hey i am creating a Firebase video app but tis error always shows up:Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseRecyclerOptions' also  by the import statement i get the error: Cannot resolve symbol 'firebase'
im am connected to firebase and also dit this in the buld.glradle :
implementation 'com.goog

le.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.3.0'

Here is my source code:
p

```
ackage com.example.coffecorner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
public class Videohome extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager2 viewpager2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videohome);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        viewpager2=(ViewPager2)findViewById(R.id.vpager);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<videomodel> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<videomodel>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("videos"), videomodel.class)
                        .build();
    }
}
```

and her the gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.coffecorner'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.coffecorner"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02"
    implementation "com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.3.0'


}
```

I read some stackoverflow questions before but they all set to make this implementations in the build.gradle but nothing helped but maybe some of you know a solution thanks (:

Comment: Have you added the proper import for `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`?

Comment: yes i did the implementations :   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.3.0' and also did the import: import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions; and did the sync

Comment: And after doing that, does it work?